# Google Checkout and Generating Unique URLs

Tags: e-commerce

I wanted to use Google Checkout and their Key/URL delivery system for digital content. I'm building a site in which the product is digital content that can only be viewed once so I need a way to generate unique URLs or keys for the customer after they purchase the content.

I found the service http://www.quixly.com/ which looks like they do what I need. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a tutorial, guide, or better way of using Google checkout with unique URLs or if anyone has had quixly with success?

Google checkout is easy enough to use I just have no idea where to start with generating unique URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these are helpful. 
Some ideas and server source code on how to implement unique urls for downloads:

[Creating unique URL/address for a resource to share - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641866/creating-unique-url-address-for-a-resource-to-share-best-practices)

[How to generate unique URL variables that match to a db record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065631/how-to-generate-unique-url-variables-that-match-to-a-db-record)

http://www.ardamis.com/2009/06/26/protecting-multiple-downloads-using-unique-urls/